# Index cfloop to php for loop

Tags: php, coldfusion, cfloop

I'm re-writing a coldfusion page in PHP.  I have an indexed cfloop and within it a cfoutput query. It looks like this:

```
    <h2>Choose up to Five Counties:</h2>
<cfif results.recordcount gt 0>
<cfloop from="1" to="5" step="1" index="i">
<!--- Looping Data --->
    <cfoutput>
    <select name="counties" style="width:150px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica; font-size:11px;">
        <option value="">- select county -
    </cfoutput> 
        <cfoutput query="results">
            <option value="#County_Name#" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica; font-size:12px;">#County_Name#</option>
        </cfoutput> 
    </select>
</cfloop>
</cfif>
```

This code loops over the select tag code 5 times and loops over a MSSQL query option tag output.  I've written the PHP side and it looks like this:

```
<h2>Choose up to Five Counties:</h2>

 <?php if(count($results) > 0) { 
    for ($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++) {
                 if ($i == 5) {
                    break;
                   } ?>

    <select name="counties" style="width:150px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica; font-size:11px;">
        <option value="">- select county -

            <?php for ($i=0; $i < count($results); $i++) { ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $results[$i]['County_Name']; ?>" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica; font-size:12px;"><?php echo $results[$i]['County_Name']; ?></option>

            <?php } ?>

    </select>
     <?php } ?>
  <?php }; ?>
```

The inner index for loop works just fine, but I can only get the outer loop to display the select tag code once and not five times (which is what I need).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're using `$i` in both loops.  So the first time it loops through the second loop, it's resetting to 0 every time.

Change your second loop variable to something like this:

```
<?php for ($x=0; $x < count($results); $x++) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $results[$x]['County_Name']; ?>" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica; font-size:12px;"><?php echo $results[$x]['County_Name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first loop should be `for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)` instead of `for ($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++)`, if you want it to show select five times.

Also, don't use `$i` for both loops, as TNC mentioned in his answer. That is why the loop exits after the first select.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could translate line for line the above, the below may be slightly more efficient. Assuming you are using the mssql_* function set:

```
<?php
$query = myssql_query('SELECT * ....');
?>

<h2>Choose up to Five Counties:</h2>
<select name="counties" style="width:150px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica; font-size:11px;">

<?php
while($results = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "<option value=\"{$results['County_Name']}\" style=\"font-family:Arial,Helvetica; font-size:12px;\">{$results['County_Name']}</option>";
}
?>

</select>
```